# The element "form" can't have a child because "form" already has a child with alias "shipment_tracking"

Tags: magento2.3.2

I don't know when this error comes out. I saw this in the exception log the first time. I never got this initially. Why this error comes. My log is like

> main.CRITICAL: The element "form" can't have a child because "form"
>   already has a child with alias "shipment_tracking".
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): The
>   element \"form\" can't have a child because \"form\" already has a
>   child with alias \"shipment_tracking\". at
>   vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:625)"} []